# Chrome DevTools getEventlisteners not working inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

I would like to access/debug the functions which are bind to specific events. For example, I can do

```
$> getEventListeners(window)
```

to see all the event bind to the `window` object, and then

```
$> debug(getEventListeners(window).focus[0].listener)
```

to start debugging.

However, in my case I have an iframe

```
<body>
   ...
   <iframe id="test" name="test" src="./inner.html"></iframe>
   ...
</body>
```

Now suppose the `inner.html` contains the following:

```
<body>
    <div class="abc">Click me</div>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('keydown', e => console.log('keydown', e));        
        document.querySelector('.abc').addEventListener('click', e => console.log('clicked', e));
    </script>
</body>
```

And I would like to debug these two listeners as I described above, it turns out that `getEventListeners` doesn't work any more (or I do something wrong!)

```
iframe = document.querySelector('iframe#game');
doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
win = iframe.contentWindow;

getEventListeners(win); // -> {}
getEventListeners(doc.querySelector('.abc')); // -> {}
```

I got `{}`, no event listeners found.

So the question is, how can I access the event listeners inside an iframe ?

Note: Because this is only for local testing/debugging I can toggle any chrome setting if needed to make this working! Any suggestions?

Comment: change the context of the debug window to be the iframe?

Comment: that sound easy :) Do you maybe have a link for me, because I have no idea how to do that

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#execution-context

Comment: Thanks a lot, I completely missed that dropdown :)

Answer (score 0):

As @epascarello comment - you need to change the context of the debug window to be the iframe

[Official documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#execution-context)